# mysql 1064 error ou have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

creating a table in phpmyadmin it shows following error![enter image description here][1]
Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`usrID` BIGINT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`mobile` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`gender` CHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`countryID` INT( 11 ) NULL ,
`stateID` INT( 11 ) NULL ,
`cityID` INT( 11 ) NULL ,
`pincode` VARCHAR( 6 ) NULL ,
`place` VARCHAR( 100 ) NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 200 ) NULL ,
`usertype` VARCHAR( 5 ) NULL ,
`pass` VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL ,
`edate` DATETIME NULL ,
`eusrID` INT( 11 ) NULL ,
`busrID` INT( 11 ) NULL ,
`adminID` INT( 11 ) NULL ,
`active` SET( 1 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = innodb
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1) NOT NULL) ENGINE = innodb' at line 1

Comment: You should read the documentation about the SET type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html .

Answer (score 2):

The value of `1` should be wrap with single quote. [See here for details.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html)

```
`active` SET( '1' ) NOT NULL
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/638ed)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you're correct. I learned something new today. All I think was the value should be wrap with single quote as shown on the demo. If i try to remove the single quotes around the value, the schema wouldn't build.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I don't see the disagreement on that page, could you be more specific? It says the the values are specified as strings, although they're represented internally as numbers.

Comment: @Barmar The comment was on an earlier version of the answer, I removed it since it's now slightly confusing :)

Comment: @Barmar my first answer was `active INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` because i didn't know about `SET`. Joachim Isaksson was right.

Answer (score 0):

[`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) takes a number of possible string values for the column, for example;

```
`color` SET('red', 'green', 'blue')
```

This would mean that the column could have the values `'red'`, `'red,blue'`, `'red,green,blue'` etc.

Your definition;

```
`active` SET(1)
```

doesn't really make any sense. Either you're looking for a boolean flag (`INT(1)`) or you need to list the possible values the field can have. Note that `SET('yes','no')` would allow all of the values `'yes'`, `'no'` and `'yes,no'` (the combination), which may not be the best choice for an `active` flag.